# D3 - loading xml data from file, using scales for barchart

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js

I'm following this great tutorial on d3 here
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch09.html#_modernizing_the_bar_chart

which introduces a bar chart in this chapter using scales. Now I wanted to load my data from an xml file but of course my code doesn't work. I'm guessing that in creating xScale and yScale variables I don't get the length of the dataset

Here is the xml file

```
<data>
<value>5</value>
<value>10</value>
<value>53</value>
<value>19</value>
<value>61</value>
<value>25</value>
<value>22</value>
<value>18</value>
<value>15</value>
<value>13</value>
<value>11</value>
<value>12</value>
<value>15</value>
<value>20</value>
<value>18</value>
<value>17</value>
<value>16</value>
<value>18</value>
<value>23</value>
<value>25</value>
</data>
```

And the code itself

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vjezba - 9.poglavlje - barchart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* No style rules here yet */       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    d3.xml("values.xml","application/xml", function(dataset) {

        var w = 600;
        var h = 250;

        //var dataset = [ 5, 10, 53, 19, 61, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];
        //radi jednakog razmaka stupova             

        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                        .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                        .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
                        .range([0, h]);

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        //Create bars       
        svg.selectAll("rect")
           .data(dataset.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("value"))
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
           })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d);
           })
           .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
           .attr("height", function(d) {
                return yScale(d);
           })
           .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
           });

    });
    /*
        //Create labels
        svg.selectAll("text")
           .data(xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("value"))
           .enter()
           .append("text")
           .text(function(d) {
                return d;
           })
           .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
           })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d) + 14;
           })
           .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
           .attr("font-size", "11px")
           .attr("fill", "white");
    */          
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I would highly recommend using JSON instead of XML -- the XML is parsed and returned as a document, which is going to be a pain to work with.

Comment: Thanks, I used json files, now i just can't understand why nothing is showing...here's the json file:
http://pastebin.com/y5dviCDW

the code:
http://pastebin.com/ZJtjqe4E

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake. You need to use the "d.value" instead of "d". Your sample data is just an array of numbers, but your JSON data is an array of objects with a "value" attribute.

Try this to see your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5edkw/1/

Since I need code to post jsfiddle links...here's a snippet of what you already know:

```
 .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
 })
```

The "/0/" version is the original you posted to pastebin.